# C# ContextMenuScript cause GCHandle leak and Memory Leak in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, .net-4.8, contextmenustrip, handle-leak

I developed an application in .net framework 4.8, it can show, switch and close different .net displays via commands with many controls inside of the display again and again, I cannot hold them in memory, because it's too many (depend on user requirement, manybe > 5,000 displays, 1000,000 .net controls), so I must use "new" and "Dispose". After switching for a while, we find the memory leak, especially GCHandle leak in Performance Monitor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IIa.png)

Debug with WinDBG, find System.WeakReference is leak, stop the switching for a long time, then print the handle value of WeakReference in WinDBG, all are null.
Notice: I already called the dispose, like b.ContextMenuScript = c;
I already called:

```
b.ContextMenuScript = null;
... // clear all event bind what I binded, clear all children in menu
c.Parent = null;
c.Dispose();
c = null;
```

What can I do right now to fix this anomaly?
Or does Microsoft give some document to describe it, do something, or it's unknown issue?

I already remote the ContextMenuScript from parent, and call it's Dispose method, it still leak. I know it maybe hold in a static object in system, but how to remove it, and how to reduce the GCHandle?

Comment: First of all, use a real memory profiler. That should ensure a GC is run before capturing any snapshot, as well as diff snapshots, and show retention graphs for objects. Finding memory leaks is a fair amount of detective work, and without an actual **minimal reproducible example** there is little possibility to provide any help. But you are probably doing *something* wrong. .Net framework itself should be fairly well tested at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I already find way to fix this issue. Cancel the ContextMenuStript binding with UI, and create and popup menu just only when user click right mouse button in runtime, the GCHandle will not leak anymore.